# Does "Carpe Via" make sense?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check

I am contemplating a run of tee shirts for the Bicycling SE site.  One of the phrases for confident cycling is to know when to **"take the lane"** which means that sometimes you have to ride in such a way that a 4 wheeled vehicle cannot pass in that lane.

I'm looking for a phrase that visually appears like "Carpe Diem" and the various copycat phrases like "Carpe Omnia", "Carpe Noctem", or the various silly ones.

Does "Carpe Via" make sense as a translation of "take the lane" ?

There doesn't appear to be a literal translation for the word "lane" either.

Google translate suggests "accipere strada " which looks more like "accept" as in "to be given the lane"  and doesn't have the same immediate recognition.

Or would it be acceptable to use a more modern word like "Carpe Strada" meaning "seize the street"?   This seems a bit much - only want to seize a lane and not the entire roadway.

Another point for "strada" is that its very close visually to the word "strava" which is a ride/cycle tracking and comparison website.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Close! You'll want *Carpe Via**m***, with an M at the end.

*Via* isn't a perfect translation of "lane", and *carpe* doesn't actually mean "seize" (it's closer to "harvest"), but the saying is well-enough-known in English and the meanings close enough that it'll be easily understandable, and the pun works better with *viam* than with any more-precise word.

Answer (score 4):

There is, also "carpe iter" = "take one's (your) way" (Pock. Ox. Lat. Dict.). This "iter" is a neuter noun, therefore, the accusative is the same as the nominative. Definitions include: journey; march; route; road; foot-way.